# WPF ToolBar: How to arrange toolbars at design-time

Tags: wpf, toolbar

I've got two Wpf ToolBars in a single ToolBarTray. How to make them fit on two rows?

I noticed users can move them at run-time. Is there a way to get the same behavior at design-time without using two ToolBarTrays ?

To sumarize, at startup, I want this:

[image]

instead of that:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Band and BandIndex to control toolbar layout.

```
    <ToolBarTray Background="White">
        <ToolBar Band="1" BandIndex="1">
            <Button Content="B1"/>
            <Button Content="B2"/>
            <Button Content="B3"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="1">
            <Button Content="B4"/>
            <Button Content="B5"/>
        </ToolBar>
        <ToolBar Band="2" BandIndex="2">
            <Button Content="B6"/>
            <Button Content="B7"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: When I change `BandIndex="2"`  to `BandIndex="1"` I still get the same result. Why is that?